# Format converted date to a specific format

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, datetime-format, iso8601

I an using javascript. Wanted to convert the indian date to specific format. The reason i wanted to do that is to use the date in 2023-05-02 format rather than in 5/2/2023.

```
let indianDateTime = new Date('2023-05-02' + 'T' + '04'+ ':' + '30' + ':' + '00.000Z').toLocaleString(undefined, {timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata'}, {dateStyle: 'full'});
console.log(indianDateTime)
```

How do i convert '5/2/2023, 10:00:00 AM' date format to '2023-05-02T10:00:00.000Z
I tried below

```
dateISTISO = new Date(indianDateTime).toISOString()
```

I also tried .replace but it didnt helped
newformatdate = indianDateTime.replace("/", "-");

Comment: I assumed your code was in JavaScript and added the javascript tag to your question. If it was wrong, please add the correct language tag instead. Thank you. (The lack of response to your question may be because users knowing JavaScript (or what language you are using) did not notice it.)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the date to UTC format first then only convert to ISOString. UTC time (Universal Time Coordinated) is same as GMT time(Greenwich Mean Time). If you directly convert to ISOString, it will show T02:00:00.000Z instead of the desired answer T10:00:00.000Z.

```js
const d = new Date('5/2/2023, 10:00:00 AM UTC');
let text = d.toISOString();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```